# Can't get preg_match to match string in PHP script (even though it works in an online tester)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm working on a PHP script to read a text file and extract certain information from it, using preg_match. I've tested the regular expression on http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/c4A and it works correctly, however, when I run the script, I get no matches.

The script snippet is as follows:

```
if (preg_match("/\/var\/www\/html\/wordpress-dev\/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)\/wp-includes\/version.php((\^@)?)\$wp_version \= \'([0-9\.]+)\'/", $line, $matches)) {
        $data[$matches[1]] = array(
            'dev_url' => $matches[1].'.my-dev-url.com',
            'dev_version' => $matches[4]
        );
    }
```

and some example content from the file I'm reading is:

```
/var/www/html/wordpress-dev/examplesite1/wp-includes/version.php^@$wp_version = '4.1.5';
/var/www/html/wordpress-dev/anotherexample/wp-includes/version.php^@$wp_version = '4.1.5';
/var/www/html/wordpress-dev/thisisanothersite/wp-includes/version.php^@$wp_version = '4.1.5';
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong with this?

Thanks!

Comment: change double to single quotes

Comment: Just tried this. Didn't work unfortunately. I assume you mean the quotes enclosing the regex string?

Comment: https://eval.in/407826

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your regex has a valid PHP variable in it and you are using double quotes:

```
"/\/var\/www\/html\/wordpress-dev\/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)\/wp-includes\/version.php((\^@)?)\$wp_version \= \'([0-9\.]+)\'/"
```

This will produce

```
"/\/var\/www\/html\/wordpress-dev\/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)\/wp-includes\/version.php((\^@)?)\ \= \'([0-9\.]+)\'/"
```

(Note that `$wp_version` has been removed)

Try using single quotes instead to prevent the variable being interpreted.